# best type in mysql for language field?

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in php and mysql,and I want to develop a multilanguage site. In my database I have users table that stores users info like `id,password,access_type,language,...`

I would to use `char(2)` type, but now I think it can't store all languages. What type i should use for language field?

I write my other field types here and I will be happy to know your opinions about them!
For `id` that is user email I use `varchar(255)`.
For `password` I use `varchar(255)` and save hashed password that password_hash method return.
For `access_type` I use `char(2)`. I use `su` for super user and `au` for amateur users.
For first name I use `varchar(32)`
for last name I use `varchar(32)`

sorry for my english because my language isn't english!!

Comment: Why not use 3 or 4 characters? I don think this will result in noticable loss of speed.

Comment: You should use another table for adding languages and link it up with a foreign key.

Comment: this field just will store language name i have another table for every language detail in my database

Comment: Does that language detail table have primary key? You should listen to @N.B. and create foreign key.

Comment: varchar(32) is useless, why not use varchar(255) immediately? Using char or any other type to store language detail is bad design. You use the foreign key that points to your language table. Now, you can use whatever else you think is good, but what I just wrote is how it's done.

Comment: i want to prevent to enter some strange and long first name and last name,because if someone enter a first name and last name with 255 character,i will have a name with 511(whith 1 space between firstname and lastname)and it certainly destoy my site design in some other places!i have languageinfo table with field languagename that is char(4) i think to change it to char(255) and use language full name instead of using 4 char!

Comment: You need to know what the varchar and char types do. Char is always fixed size. Varchar, as the name says, is variable. It stores a number next to the data so MySQL can know how long the string is. In 1 byte integer, you can store up to 256 numbers (0 - 255). That's why varchar(32) is silly. That's why you don't do this validation on the database size. Also, what if some time in the future you actually need to store some person's name who has an absurdly long name? These things are what a data modeler has to take into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use anything between 2 to 4 as per you requirement.better
>   create a foreign key instance in some other table where you are having
>   detailed information about the languages. for foreign key concept you
>   can visit
>   here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

enum can also be handy.

Comment: thanks for your recommends,i will use foreign key and char(4) type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum if I wanted to make sure that only the values that are acceptable are the only choices. The other change that I would make is the id column. I would change that to an auto-increment id and set the email field as an email. You can still authenticate a user by that but when you need to run operations like edit, delete, etc... you can use the user's "id" which would be faster than looking up against the email all the time. Performance is going to depend on how many records are in the database as well. If we're talking a few thousand records, I wouldn't worry about it too much, but if it's a large amount of records, you may need to optimize more.

Comment: thank for your recommend i will use an auto id and another field for email,it will improve performance,i'm not sure about users but i guess my records will be at least 10000!